# apr-utils apr_strmatch regex syntax

Tags: c, regex, apr

I want to port the following regex from python:

```
HASH_REGEX = re.compile("([a-fA-F0-9]{32})")
if HASH_REGEX.match(target):
    print "We have match"
```

to C with apr-utils apr_strmatch function:

```
pattern = apr_strmatch_precompile(pool, "([a-fA-F0-9]{32})", 0);
if (NULL != apr_strmatch(pattern, target, strlen(target)) {
    printf("We have match!\n");
}
```

The problem is that I don't understand what syntax of regex (or dialect) apr-utils apr_strmatch function is using. Search for documentation and examples ended with no results.

Thanks for your advices in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apr_strmatch` doesn't do regular expression matching at all; it does ordinary substring search using the [Boyer–Moore–Horspool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore%E2%80%93Horspool_algorithm) algorithm (see [source](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/apr/apr/trunk/strmatch/apr_strmatch.c)).

For RE matching in C, try [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/).